# How to run one function twice in parallel with Intel TBB?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, stl, parallel-processing, tbb

I have a function that I need to run twice with different data parameters. This function takes long time to run and does heavy computational job.

How I can do that, with which TBB mechanism? Or not even TBB, if I can do this with STL, please give me an example.

**UPD:**

For example I have a function that takes as a parameter image and does some processing to it:

```
int Compute(cv::Mat I)
{

    /*    computations    */

    return 0;
}
void callf(cv::Mat I1, cv::Mat I2)
{
    // make call of this functions parallel
    Compute(I1);
    Compute(I2);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean templates?  Without knowing what exactly you are trying to do, it would be difficult to suggest any STL data structure.

Comment: So you mean threading? Maybe have a look at [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`tbb::task_group`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_groups/task_group_cls.html) or [`tbb::parallel_invoke`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_invoke_func.html) in conjunction with lambda functions like here:

```
void callf(cv::Mat I1, cv::Mat I2)
{
    // make call of this functions parallel
    tbb::parallel_invoke(
        [&]{ Compute(I1); },
        [&]{ Compute(I2); }
    );
}
```